# Build Child object observable with Parent object observable Angular

Tags: c#, angular, rxjs

I work on a Angular project, I'm trying to populate a child object property with its parents by using rxjs operator.
The objects look like this

```js
[
 {idSite:1,siteName:"Site of First Enseigne", enseigneId:1,enseigne: null},
 {idSite:1,siteName:"Site of Second Enseigne", enseigneId:2,enseigne: null},
]

[
 {idEnseigne:1,name:"First Enseigne", sites:[]},
 {idEnseigne:2,name:"Second Enseigne", sites:[]},
]
```

I would like to get the sites with their enseignes:

```js
[
 {
  idSite:1,
  siteName:"Site of First Enseigne", 
  enseigneId:1,
  enseigne: {idEnseigne:1,name:"First Enseigne", sites:[]}
 },
 {
  idSite:1,
  siteName:"Site of Second Enseigne", 
  enseigneId:2,
  enseigne: {idEnseigne:2,name:"Second Enseigne", sites:[]}
 },
]
```

I use a site service

```js
fetchAllSites() : Observable<Site[]>{ // which request all site in my API
    let url = `${this.provider}all`;
    return this.http.get<Site[]>(url);
}
```

And an enseigne service which work as site service

I tried to populate all site value from fetchAllSites with that method but maybe I am not doing in the right way

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, {

  sites!: Site[]
  enseignes!: Enseigne[]

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.LoadTabcomponent();

  }

  LoadTabcomponent(){
   this.siteService.fetchAllSites().pipe(
       map(sites => {
         sites.map( site => {
           this.enseigneService.getEnseignes().pipe(
             map( enseignes => {
               enseignes.map( enseigne => {
                 if(site.enseigneId === enseigne.idEnseigne){
                   site.enseigne = enseigne
                 }
               })
             })
           )
         })
       })
     ) 
  }

}
```

My web API is in c#, I should get the complete object from the API but it doesn't support the serialization cause I got more object to complete to get what I want, so I'm trying to build the object in the Webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `combineLatest` or `forkJoin` operators to merge both results like so:

```
combineLatest([
  this.siteService.fetchAllSites(),
  this.enseigneService.getEnseignes()
]).pipe(
  map([sites, enseignes] => {
    ... you merge code here
  })
).subscribe((sites)=> this.sites = sites);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the solution work well with CombineLatest and ForkJoin. I'd like to add that the result of the operator will be void so to subscribe to the value I had ``.subscribe((sites) => this.sites = sites as unknown as Site[] ``